# PHP memory leak with Apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento, memory

I have a VPS LAMP server hosting a magento website.

I have recently been noticing performance issues, so I attempted to optimize my apache, mysql, and php settings.

However, it seems to me that the apache php5 module is taking a ridiculous amount of memory.

if I run the command - sudo ps aux | awk '{sum1 += $4}; END {print sum1};'

I get an average of about 105 MB! per apache process.

Now, if I turn off php5 by disabling the module and restarting apache, and run the command again I get about 30-40 mb per process.

Finally, if I enable the php5 module again, it will slowly start to increase until it reaches 100+ mb per process again. It takes about 3-5 minutes to get back up there. I also notice that the CPU usage spikes very high with no load.

Some of my apache2.conf file reads:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers 4
MinSpareServers 15
MaxSpareServers 30
MaxClients 250
MaxRequestsPerChild 300
</IfModule>
```

My server has 2GB ram.

It looks like a memory leak to me, but I cannot determine what is causing such high memory usage.

Any insight on this issue would be very much appreciate, thank you.

Comment: You didn't say anything about Magento but did include the tag so this might be relevant.  Magento [requires 256MB minimum](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements) and I've seen it go way over.  By including PHP memory rises by ~70MB which is well within normal usage, and that is allocated mem which tends to overestimate.  I'd be more concerned with making sure caches are working efficiently.

Comment: Sounds about right, you might try using Apache MPM-Worker and FastCGI if it's that great a concern to you. Frankly a 2GB server for a Magento site is kind of laughable. You've after all got to have a database, web server processes and enough memory left over to run the OS at the end of the day. It's all in the ridiculous amount of memory and resources you aren't giving an advanced PHP Web application that's probably hurting.